# Master detail page using MVVM

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
public MainPageView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MasterPage.NavMenuMListView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;
        }

        void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MasterNavigationItem item = (MasterNavigationItem)e.SelectedItem;
            if (item != null)
            {
                Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.Target));
                MasterPage.NavMenuMListView.SelectedItem = null;
                IsPresented = false;
            }
        }
```

I have a master detail page(this is the code behind) and i want to respect mvvm conventions. this approach that is used in the docs uses the model inside the view. how can i make that onitemselected function in the viewmodel?

Comment: bind it to a command in the XAML

Comment: but i need the MainPageView to set the detail and etc

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with the suggestion that I made

Answer (score 0):

> how can i make that onitemselected function in the viewmodel?

Download the source file from the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/navigation-masterdetailpage/

I make some changes with the source file. Use the command to binding for the listview with the ItemSelected event.

Install the package on NuGet.

`Xamarin.Forms.BehaviorsPack`: https://github.com/nuitsjp/Xamarin.Forms.BehaviorsPack

MasterPage.xaml

```
  <ListView.Behaviors>
            <behaviorsPack:SelectedItemBehavior Command="{Binding SelectedItemCommand}" />
        </ListView.Behaviors>
```

MainPage.cs

```
 public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public ICommand SelectedItemCommand { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SelectedItemCommand = new Command(execute: () =>
        {
            var item = masterPage.listView.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;

            if (item != null)
            {
                Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
                masterPage.listView.SelectedItem = null;
                IsPresented = false;
            }
        });

        masterPage.BindingContext = this;
        //masterPage.listView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

        //if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP)
        //{
        //    MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;
        //}
    }

    //void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
    //    if (item != null)
    //    {
    //        Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
    //        masterPage.listView.SelectedItem = null;
    //        IsPresented = false;
    //    }
    //}
}
```